# Tip for sqlite count performance

Tags: performance, sqlite

I want to show an html page of the results of a sql query. My database can get to 500K record and beyond, but I'm running an ARM9 CPU.
Therefore, if I run a

```
select count (*) where timeStamp < '2013-05-01'
```

I have to wait about 30sec. before having an answer. I think I need to do this query because I want to show some kind of pagination of the results and therefore I need to know how many records matches the requested criteria. Is this the only way? Is there any tip for speeding things up?

EDIT: clarified the query

Comment: Any slowness isn't caused by `count (*)`, it's caused by your `XXX`.  Perhaps you should share the rest of the query so that it might be optimised...

Comment: Is `timeStamp` an indexed field?

Comment: No. Am I missing something? The database is a record log with a timestamp and some data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment: yes - it sounds like you're missing an index!

Searching or sorting on a column in any database is much improved when said column is indexed.  Indexing stores extra information about the data in a column so that the data in it is more quickly traversed.

You will want to run Sql something like this to create your index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tableName_columnName ON tableName (columnName ASC)
```